# search query to compare a particular word from a string to values of another string in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am making a search module in which i require to search details of users matching the details of other user for that i need to compare user details . for details like `age`, `gender` etc i have used `like '%search_term%'` and was able to get the results i wanted but i am not able to make a query for details like user 1 speaks `english,french,spanish` so its stored in database like words seperated by comma as the same markup. and suppose other user just have one language in common `latin,hindi,french` ie french in common then how to filter that user too according to user 1's details as such he/she still have something in common. The following query is for normal values such as age

```
select * from users_profile 
where age like '%$search_term%' 
order by created_time DESC
```

how to make that query within this one using `AND` and get the results?

Comment: Storing non-scalar data (such as a coma-separated list of items) in one field is very bad practice. Instead you should create a second table (eg. `user_language (user_id, language)`). Your problem then becomes easy to solve.

Comment: thank you for the sugestion @YaK but the whole system i am working upon has this system by default . i am just making a new module for search . can you please help me out with the way to accomplish the search result query i am making which is incomplete at the moment

Comment: MySQL is unhandy to handle strings, to say the least. You'd probably be better off splitting the coma-separated string at the application layer, and then generate the SQL query based on this list. It *is* possible to do it in MySQL only, but I have this funny feeling it would look really ugly :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a self join and then replace the commas in one of them with pipes and then use that regular expression with rlike.    Performance is likely to be horrible.

```
select users_profile.*, users_profile2.id as other_id, 
  users_profile2.language as other_lang from users_profile
  inner join users_profile as users_profile2 on
    users_profile.language rlike 
      replace(users_profile2.language,",","|") 
    and users_profile.id != users_profile2.id;
```

You can see for yourself:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9549f/6

Comment: thanks a lot @ShawnBalestracci this really worked and thank you YaK for the suggestion

Comment: Note languages like French and French-Canadian would be matched, which may not be a problem in your situation but might warrant adjustment if this is to be used elsewhere.